# magento 1.9 Admin menus are not working

Tags: magento-1.9, adminmenu

I have installed a extension for news blog from https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/news-by-commercelab.html
After installing this extension the admin menus are not working now .
Please tell me any solution .
Thank you

Comment: have you checked the system logs and console logs. if not please check the same ?

Comment: Please share us screenshot what exact problem you are facing so that i can guide you. thanks

Comment: the exact problem is only about the menus.... i can't click any menu. Only one menu is clickable that is dashboard. no sub menu is showing. and i have no idea about system logs and console logs because i am begineers. please help me

Comment: is there any solution

Comment: let me know whether you have installed the extension through connect manager http://prntscr.com/fe49k2

Comment: yes i have installed the extension through connect manager

Comment: As per u r question i have installed and tried it from my end it is working properly http://prntscr.com/fe4cg9 . please confirm after installed did u clear cache and session from var folder? if not do it once and check the same.

Comment: where should i find the var folder

Comment: goto magentorootFolder/var/ just rename or remove the cache and session folders

Comment: i have removed folders but same situation, menus are still not working

Comment: okey, can you help me to uninstall that news blog.... may be menus started working after it

Comment: please help me to solve out this problem

Comment: Yes manish,  please uninstall CommerceLab_News.xml and clear cache and  session and check it once

Comment: but i want to know that now when menus are not working then how can i uninstall. and where i find the CommerceLab_News.xml

Comment: MagentoRootFolder/app/etc/modules/CommerceLab_News.xml  just change the true=>false and clear cache and session

Comment: thank you so much..................... its working now. thanx a lot.

Comment: sounds good you are welcome manish.

Comment: i want one more help only.... how can i add a blog into my magento 1.9 set up

Comment: is there any other free extension for it, please suggest me